# Using Bash to delete a bracket delimited substring from string variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, centos7

I have this string in a variable:

```
strVar="Hello World [randomSubstring].zip"
```

I would like to extract `[randomSubstring]`, where that substring inside the brackets could be anything.

The expected result must be something like this:

```
echo "$strVar"
Hello World .zip
```

I tried several combinations with grep and awk but without success, I am using CentOS 7.

```
echo "Hello World [RNVE5Z].zip" | grep -oP '(?<=[).*(?=])'
echo "Hello World [RNVE5Z].zip" | awk -F"["" '{print $1}' | awk -F"]" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: show your code please. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: OK, so [randomSubstring] can be anything. If the rest is always `Hello World .zip`, you already know the answer.

Comment: I added some code, but not sure how to get it working

Comment: I just want to remove everything inside the brackets, including them

Comment: Try piping the value to `sed -e 's/\[.*\]//'`

Comment: Awesome, thanks, it worked for me: `echo "Hello World [RNVE5Z].zip" | sed -e 's/\[.*\]//'`

Comment: note that `sed` normally uses greedy matching, so if you have `stuff [more stuff] other things [other stuff] ending stuff` you wind up with `stuff ending stuff`, losing `other things`. There is a solution to this, but not fun, and not clear if your data has this problem). Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash only:

```
echo ${strVar/\[*\]/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use bash's substring manipulation:

```
echo ${strVar/\[*\]/}
```

I would prefer it over an external call to sed, except there is more to be done, why I use sed anyway:

```
echo $strVar | sed 's/\[.*\]//'
```

I don't think there is an elegant solution for grep but might be wrong. In awk I'm not that fluent.